# Tag suggestion for "consciousness"

Tags: discussion, tags

Consciousness according to Wikipedia:

> At one time consciousness was viewed with skepticism by many
>   scientists, but in recent years it has become a significant topic of
>   research in psychology, neuropsychology and neuroscience. The primary
>   focus is on understanding what it means biologically and
>   psychologically for information to be present in consciousness—that
>   is, on determining the neural and psychological correlates of
>   consciousness.

See also Science magazine: [What Is the Biological Basis of Consciousness?](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/309/5731/79.full).

Suggested example questions to tag with consciousness:

- [How is consciousness linked to the brain?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8767/how-is-consciousness-linked-to-the-brain)
- [Which organisms have the neuroanatomy Roger Penrose supposes play a role in consciousness?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/which-organisms-have-the-neuroanatomy-roger-penrose-supposes-play-a-role-in-cons)
- [Why are things conscious?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10217/why-are-things-conscious/10967#10967)
- [How is consciousness linked to the brain?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8767/how-is-consciousness-linked-to-the-brain/8777#8777)

etc.